# How to watch the file change and compare the two files in python?

Tags: python

I have a requirement where I need to do the following:

1. Watch a file for any changes - done
2. Compare the file with the changed file - pending

   - That means, say I have a text file with the content "hello world" as below:

`hello.txt`

```
hello world
```

Then I will add another line to the same file as below

```
hello world
some other line
```

up on the save, it should create a new file without actually writing to the same file so, I should end up with two files instead of one:

1. `hello.txt` - original file

```
hello world
```

2. `hello_modified.txt` - modified (appended) file

```
hello world
some other
```

How can I do this with `python` ?

I have already used `watchdog` for listening to file modification, I have even implemented the function to display the diff between the two files too. But I have no idea how to write the logic for the file replication. i.e. how can I create and write to another file up on saving the `hello.txt` without really saving the `hello.txt` ?

Comment: "...it should create a new file..." what should?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. I think that "it" refers to the system being developed. When the first file is modified, the modifications should go to a new file and the first file be reset.

Comment: What should happen if there is a second modification of the file? Say that first a line "edit1" is added to the first file. Then that line should be moved to the second file and the first file be reset to just have "hello world". If then the line "edit2" is added to the first file, should another file `hello_modified_2.txt`be created with "hello world" and "edit2"? Or should the line be added to the already existing `hello_modified.txt` so that it now has the lines "hello world", "edit1" and "edit2"?

Comment: Have you considered doing it the other way: when an external program changes a file, save the old version to a new file? This would probably make more sense in the case that the file is opened in another program.

Comment: @md2perpe: When the second time file (`hello.txt`) modifies, the original file (`hello.txt`) should be replaced by the content of `hello_modified.txt` and the newly added changes should be appended/write to `hello_modified_.txt`. Does that make sense?

Comment: So a new history file for each new line? And the original file should be replaced by the last history file?

Comment: @md2perpe exactly what I need. Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using a `while` loop and `time` module. Note that, reading a file each time a while statements loops over itself, is probitively expensive for your computer processor. So, in this answer, I decided to check the files every 3 seconds.

```py
from time import time

startTime = time()
diffTime = 3
with open("hello.txt") as f:
  checkFile = f.read()
while True:
  now = time()
  if now > startTime+diffTime:
    startTime = now
    with open("hello.txt") as f:
      myString = f.read()
    if checkFile != myString:
      with open("hello_modified.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(myString)
      with open("hello.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(checkFile)
```

Comment: When the second time file (hello.txt) modifies, the original file (hello.txt) should be replaced by the content of hello_modified.txt and the newly added changes should be appended/write to hello_modified_.txt. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JananathBanuka This code does the same, I think!

Comment: It always reset the `'hello.txt` to empty value. On each iteration I need to replace the value of `hello.txt` by the content of `hello_modified.txt`

Comment: @JananathBanuka don't you want the original file to get back to original format after modification? Because, from your question, I thought you might be interested in changing back the file to the previous format. In this case, the main/original file will always go back to what it was before running the script.

Comment: No it wasn't my requirement. Can we have a call and check this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using a coroutine `file_copier`. See `usage` and `test` for usage.

```py
import itertools
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def copy(src: Path, dst: Path):
    print(f"Copying {src} to {dst}")
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

def file_copier(watched_path: str|Path):
    if isinstance(watched_path, str):
        watched_path = Path(watched_path)

    shutil.copyfile(watched_path, watched_path.with_stem(f'{watched_path.stem}_0'))

    for counter in itertools.count():
        yield
        copy(watched_path, watched_path.with_stem(f'{watched_path.stem}_{counter+1}'))
        copy(watched_path.with_stem(f'{watched_path.stem}_{counter}'), watched_path)



path = Path("hello.txt")

def usage():
    fc = file_copier(path)
    next(fc)    # start/init

    # When 'hello.txt' has been modified:
    next(fc)    # copies 'hello.txt' to new history file and resets 'hello.txt' to previous history file



# TEST

def create():
    """Creates empty 'hello.txt'"""
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        pass

def append(line: str):
    """Simulates modification of 'hello.txt'"""
    with open("hello.txt", "a") as f:
        print(line, file=f)

def test():
    fc = file_copier(path)

    create()
    append("hello world")
    next(fc)

    append("edit 1")
    next(fc)

    append("edit 2")
    next(fc)

    append("edit 3")
    next(fc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: That is cool, but when I pass a `json` object instead of `hello.txt` i get the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'with_stem'`

Comment: You should pass a `pathlib.Path` object, not a string.

Comment: I can change it so that it accepts a string. Just a minute...

Comment: The function has been updated.

Comment: Thank you. I am Getting this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'`

Comment: Okay I fixed it, but could you tell me how can I get use of `usage` function? Kind of stuck on how to use it

Comment: than you for your answer. But one caveat I see is that, you are `appending` some text file to the `hello.txt` What if we manually add it? using `vim` editor or open the `hello.txt` with a text editor? how to track those changes?

Comment: In `test` I append the text to the file programmatically just to simulate adding text manually. You wrote in your post that you had solved how to watch for file changes: "Watch a file for any changes - done". When you get a notification that the file has changed, call `next(fc)`. Note that there is one initial call `next(fc)`. That copies `hello.txt` to `hello_0.txt` and then waits for next call.

Comment: Thank you, but here I have done only the handler part where it watches for any changes to the file and notify. It doesn't return what changes we did.

Comment: You don't need to get the changes to use my code.